# Particles reproduce after a delay, what is the population after $m$ months?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have been working on the following puzzle:

> A seed particle produces 'r' particles/month.
>   Each of these particles must wait at least 's' months before producing 'r' particles/month.
>   Consequently, each new set of particles must wait 's' months before producing 'r' particles/month.
>   Assuming a rate of 'r' particles/month and a wait period of 's' months, how many particles will be produced after 'm' months?

Through trial and error, I have arrived at the following:
$$ P_t(m, r, s) = 1 + \sum_{n = 1}^{ceil(\frac{m}{s+1})}\binom{m-s(n-1)}{n}r^{n} $$
$$ m \geq 0, r \geq 0, s \geq 0$$

Notice when $s = 0$, the function reduces to:
$$ P_t(m, r, 0) = (r + 1)^{m} $$

I would like to whether the original function can be reduced in a similar fashion.